# Active Directory - systemFlags value on attributes

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to write a script to determine if an attribute of the userClass is a category 1 or category 2.

Microsoft states, that if the systemFlags value is 16, then its a category 1.
If no systemFlags appear on an attribute, then its a category 2.

But what if the SystemFlags value is something other than 16.

For example on my test AD server, I have the attribute called uSNLastObjRem which has the value 19. What category is that then?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/querying-for-category-1-or-2-schema-objects
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-systemflags

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cVp7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The attribute called ‘uSNLastObjRem’ is a sub class of ‘Top’ class which is a schema administrator class, also it has own ‘CN=Top’ as mentioned in the image you specified. Since, the object-category of ‘Top’ class is 2, the object-category of ‘uSNLastObjRem’ is also 2 since it being a sub class of the ‘Top’ class.

Also, the system flag value as seen from the image as uploaded by you is in decimal format, i.e., 19 which in hexadecimal if converted is ‘0x00000013’, i.e., 13. According to the official Microsoft documentation, the ‘Top’ schema class has schema administrator privileges which cannot be modified by anyone. Thus, this system flag value is embedded in the design of AD attributes from the initial phase, and it can be anything for any sub class from the ‘Top’ class. As the documentation doesn’t state that the system flag value of object-category 2 attributes will be definitive/defined or fixed. It can be anything.

Please find the below official documentation for your reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/c-top

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-systemflags

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-usnlastobjrem

Thanking you,

Answer (score 0):

`systemFlags` is a [*bitfield*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) - a value of 19 (`0x13`) means that the following 3 flags are set:

- `0x01` - attribute is not replicated
- `0x02` - attribute is part of the Global Catalog attribute set
- `0x10` - attribute is Category 1, part of the base schema

Comment: Does mean that a category 1 attribute is an attribute with the systemFlags value of AT LEAST 16. Not necessarily 16, but just at least 16?